# unable to get lat long in api call

Tags: data.gov, api, collegescorecard

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude for different schools, and keep getting an error. Location is at the root, and I am able to get ids which are also at the root, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This does not work: https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools?_fields=location.lon&school.name=pepperdine&api_key=**********

but this does:
https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools?_fields=id&school.name=pepperdine&api_key=***********

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Appears to be a defect / mismatch of functionality with the API. Perhaps an idiosyncracy with the underlying API-maker https://github.com/18F/open-data-maker/blob/api-docs/API.md . Your logic isn't flawed.. it's something odd. Sidenote: I dont see why location isn't nested within school. Also, as a workaround, for your use case, can you just get back all fields and extract location using your code?

Comment: Hi Skram, yes, I used a workaround of just I getting all the school ids, making a call for each id, and than getting the lat long that way. However, this requires a lot more code and API calls, and I am hitting my limit for API calls pretty quickly. So good to know it's a bug!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much for finding this, and I'm sorry for the inconvenience. We've verified that this is indeed a bug. I've created an issue for it here: https://github.com/18F/open-data-maker/issues/227

Thanks,

Holly Allen
Product Lead
18F